# SelectedItem of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am developing a User Interface for a host monitoring application, which is already being monitored on database level. I have displayed 2 datagrids on my UI which will populate on run time.These two datagrids are connected by the HostID ( HostID is the Foreign Key in the LogDatagrid).

The First datagrid displays the list of Host with their Status(either Running or Stopped).
I would like to display the Log Status of the respective HostID when a user wants to know the status in detail. How to achieve this when a user selects the Host ID in the HostDatagrid ? I have added my XAML and screenshot of my UI.

[image: UI Design]

XAML

```
 <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Path=HostData,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,Mode=OneWay}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="hostDatagrid" Margin="171,32,235,230">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Host" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding HostID}" />
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding HostStatus}"/> 
     </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
 <DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Path=LogData,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True,Mode=OneWay}"
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="LogDatagrid" Margin="103,108,102,145">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Host ID" Width="auto"  Binding="{Binding HostID}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Logs" Width="auto"  Binding="{Binding LogID}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Log Path" Width="auto"  Binding="{Binding LogPath}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="auto"  Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Activity" Width="auto"  Binding="{Binding LastActivity}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
```

code behind for the LogFile Model:

```
    public LogFileModel()
    {

    }
    private int _hostID;
    public int HostID
    {
        get { return _hostID; }
        set { _hostID= value; OnpropertyChanged("HostID"); }
    }

    private string _logid;
    public string LogID
    {
        get { return _logid; }
        set { _logid= value; OnpropertyChanged("LogID"); }
    }

    private string _logpath;
    public string LogPath
    {
        get { return _logPath; }
        set { _logPath = value; OnpropertyChanged("LogPath"); }
    }

    private DateTime _date;
    public DateTime Date;
    {
        get { return _date; }
        set { _date= value; OnpropertyChanged("Date"); }
    }

    private bool _activity;
    public bool LastActivity
    {
        get { return _activity; }
        set { _activity= value; OnpropertyChanged("LastActivity"); }
    }
```

Code behind for the LogFile ViewModel :

```
    LogModel _myModel = new LogModel();
    private ObservableCollection<LogFileModel> _logFileData = new  ObservableCollection<LogFileModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<LogFileModel> LogFileData
    {
        get { return _logFileData; }
        set { _logFileData = value; OnPropertyChanged("LogFileData"); }
    }
   public LogFileViewModel()
    {
        initializeload();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        timer.Start();
    }

    ~LogFileViewModel()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                timer.Stop();
                timer.Tick -= new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
            }
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            LogFileData.Clear();
            initializeload();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
    }

    private void initializeload()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable table = _myModel.getData();

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; ++i)
                LogFileData.Add(new LogFileModel
                {
                   HostID= Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[i][0]),
                   LogID = table.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                   LogPath = table.Rows[i][2].ToString(),
                   Date = Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows[i][3]),
                   LastAcivity= table.Rows[i][4].ToString(),                   
                });
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
    }

    public class LogModel
    {
        public DataTable getData()
        {
            DataTable ndt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            sqlcon.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [LocalDB].[dbo].[LogFiles]", sqlcon);
            da.Fill(ndt);
            da.Dispose();
            sqlcon.Close();
            return ndt;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have followed the same pattern for the Host Model and ViewModel too.

Comment: if you can access the data grid by code you can get the selecteditems list from the datagrid itself on the selected change event

Comment: yes, but from should I bind the selectedItems ?? I have not declared any selectedItem in my c# code.. do I have to do that ?

Comment: @Buba1947 Yes you should use a selected item. Look at my answer below for an example of how to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to have the following in your code viewmodel

A SelectedItem which will hold the selected item in the first DataGrid.
A collection HostData that holds all of your hosts.
An empty collection Log Data which will display the logs for a particular host

```
//populate with all your hosts and this will bind to your first datagrid
private ObservableCollection<HostModel> _hostData= new ObservableCollection<Host>();

public ObservableCollection<HostModel> HostData
{
    get { return _hostData; }
    set { _hostData= value; OnPropertyChanged("HostData"); }
}

//populate with all the logs for the selected item and bind this to your second datagrid
private ObservableCollection<LogFileModel> _logFileData = new ObservableCollection<LogFileModel>();

public ObservableCollection<LogFileModel> LogFileData
{
    get { return _logFileData; }
    set { _logFileData = value; OnPropertyChanged("LogFileData"); }
}

//when the user selects an item in the first datagrid this property will hold the value
//so you will bind it to the selected item property of your first datagrid
private Host _selectedHost; //initialise to avoid null issues

public HostModelSelectedHost
{
    get{ return _selectedItem; } 
    set 
    {
        //call a method to populate you second collection
        _selectedHost = value;
        logFileData = GetLogsForSelectedHost(_selectedHost);
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedHost");
    { 
}

//the method for populating your second collection could look like this
private ObservableCollection<LogFileModel> GetLogsForSelectedHost(_selectedHost)
{
    ObservableCollection<LogFileModel> filteredLogs = new ObservableCollection<LogFileModel>;

    filteredLogs = //fill the collection with all the logs that match the host ID of
                   //your selected item
    return filteredLogs ;
}
```

I am not sure from your code which class is which but I hope the code above can show you the way of doing this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply..kindly look at my edited question I have added code blocks for the Model.cs and ViewModel.cs for the log Datagrid

Comment: do I have to declare the "private Host _selectedHost;" in my HostModel class ?

Comment: No, that will go in the viewmodel. I am assuming you have one viewmodel for the one Interface screen?

Comment: I have two view Models actually ( one for Host and for Log)

Comment: @Buba1947 I did not know that your 'Host' class was called HostModel. I have updated my answer to replace `Host` with `HostModel`. Hope there was no confusion

Comment: What is the reason for having two viewmodels? If you need to have two then you will have to do this a little differently. The HostModel collection and HostModel selectedItem will be in the viewmodel dealing with your first datagrid and it's bindings. The LogFileViewmodel will have a collection bound to the second datagrid. In the `set` of your selected item you will have to call a public method on your logfileviewmodel that can accept a hostId (or an entire HostModel object) and will fill the logfile collection based on that parameter.

Comment: many thanks for ur reply. ur above comment is little confusing!! 
what do u mean by " In the set of your selected item you will have to call a public method on your logfileviewmodel that can accept a hostId (or an entire HostModel object) and will fill the logfile collection based on that parameter". could you please edit the code what are you talking about.. that would be more clearer.

Comment: I am trying to implement your solution. it seems to give me a better idea.. but I guess you have some error in this code

Answer (score 1):

DO something like this :

creat a method in your main datamodel called search. Search has a query to search your other databse which holds the data log and returns a data table. 
Then add a CellClick listener method for your Host Status Datagrid and do something like below. I hope I am undrestanding what you need .

```
private void hostDatagrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string cellValue = hostDatagrid[e.ColumnIndex,e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        LogFileViewModel logFileViewModel = new LogFileViewModel();
        DataTable table = logFileViewModel.search(cellValue);
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = table;
        logDataGrid.Datasource = table;
        logDataGrid.Update();
        logDataGrid.Refresh();
    }

   // and add this method to  LogFileViewModel



 public DataTable Search(string hostID)
    {
        DataTable ndt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        sqlcon.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE hostid ="+hostID, sqlcon);
        da.Fill(ndt);
        da.Dispose();
        sqlcon.Close();
        return ndt;


    }
```

Comment: This is obviously is not the best way to do that, but I have no idea how your datamodel is set, let me know how you getting on . All the best

Comment: no is not, tell me how to do you set your Datagridview? so I can tell you exactly what to do . What is your current SQL query to search your databse?

Comment: kindly look at my edited question I have added the Model and ViewModel for the log Datagrid

Comment: This should work, add the search method to your LogFileViewModel. Let me know if this works

Comment: I dont know the name of the table you have so change Whatever to the name of your table also change the hostid name to the correct name :)

Comment: hello Kevin, I am trying to implement your soultion, but I have many errors

Answer (score 1):

1) Bind your `SelectedItem` to a `Host` property in your ViewModel from your `Host` `DataGrid`

```
SelectedItem = {Binding SelectedHost, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

2) Assuming LogData is an ObservableCollection, in the setter for `SelectedHost` property, update LogData to show the logs for the `Host`.

```
public Host SelectedHost {
    get;
    set {
        SelectedHost = value;
        UpdateLogData();
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedHost");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to bind your the selected time to an object in your viewmodel and whenever this value changes you can change the collection LogData to show what you want.

Comment: I have already connected the two tables using HostID. All I want to display is the logstatus for the respective  HostID. I have used Observable collection<list> to bind the data from the DB and then display on the UI.